# What is the morpheme that marks a question called?

Tags: terminology, morphology, morphemes, interrogatives

When languages have a morpheme attached to the word that makes it a question, such as a suffix, is this called a question suffix, an interrogative, suffix, etc? I don't have much experience in morphology to know the terms used to label morphemes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most often it is called an interrogative {particle/prefix/suffix}. There's no intrinsic reason for using the 25-cent word "interrogative" rather than "question", but "interrogative" is a fancy-register word.

Comment: Probably, the reason of using *interrogative* in favor of *question* is that the latter may imply the entire sentence, while former denotes only a morpheme or another grammatic feature.